# My "div" is moving from top to bottom (i.e 200px height from top) and fix on a top(starting postion). but I want to fix on a bottom.How can I do it?

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML `div` element moving from `top` to `bottom` and fix on a `top`, but I want to fix on a `bottom`, I mean, I want to fix my `div` `200px` from `top`.

```
   @keyframes mymove {
      from {top: 0px;}
      to {top: 200px;}
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body >
    <input type="button" id="mybtn" onclick="myfunction()" value="click 
   me">
    <div id="abc" style="display:none" >
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  <script>
      function myfunction(){
      document.getElementById("abc").style.display="block";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.width="500px";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.height="100px";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.border="2px solid red";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.position="absolute";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.animation="mymove 1s";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.marginTop="200px";
      document.getElementById("mybtn").style.display="none";
    }
  </script>
```

I expect that my `div` element come out from `top` to `bottom` and fix on a `bottom`

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be complete. `<style>` tag is missing (and probably other style elements). Please post the complete code so as to make it easy to reproduce the problem.

Comment: no no no. I am using <style> tag, it's above on keyframes

Comment: So is it like this? `<style> @keyframes ... </style>`

Comment: yes...  you are right

Comment: problem solved after adding this document.getElementById("abc").style.animation="mymove 1s forwards" and comment the next line

Comment: If any of the posted answers solved your problem, you may want to chose one of them as the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add forwards property to your animation. So your script will be as follows.

```
 <script>
      function myfunction(){
      document.getElementById("abc").style.display="block";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.width="500px";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.height="100px";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.border="2px solid red";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.position="absolute";
      document.getElementById("abc").style.animation="mymove 1s forwards"; //Here you add forwards
      //document.getElementById("abc").style.marginTop="200px";
      document.getElementById("mybtn").style.display="none";
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that you want the animated object to keep the last position on the animation.

Add the next line to your code:

```
document.getElementById("abc").style.animationFillMode = "forwards";
```

Or if you already have a CSS definition for the element, you can add it directly into the CSS:

```
#abc {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

You can find more details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).